# Android studio build gradle issue

Tags: android-studio

I'm having problems trying to build gradle in android studio version 3.2.1. I have tried some of the solutions provided on stack overflow but none works.  It keeps saying 'Gradle sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.' also keeps saying that the cause is service.gradle.org but I've not gotten any help. Also the xml file has lots of errors saying that attributes are not allowed there.

Check the picture below:

[image]

Comment: You should paste the error traceback instead of including a screenshot / picture of it.

Comment: Please post *stack trace* directly.